# Why dose notification raise while setting time of notification?

Tags: java, android, time, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I have used time picker to set the time of notification by user. I have used alarm manager and notification builder.

I have called the setAlarm method on clickListener of a button to save data. So when this setAlarm method gets called Notification raises at the same time as well as it raises at the time user have set.

I don't want it to be raised when I save the data.

Can anyone tell why this is happening?

**setAlarm method**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetmCalen) {

    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "call alarmManager.setExact()",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    intent.putExtra("title",eventTitle);


    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetmCalen.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}
```

**NotificationReceiver**

```
public class NotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification myNotification;

    EventTableHelper db;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Toast.makeText(context, "Time is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        db = new EventTableHelper(context);

        List<EventData> testSavings = db.getAllEvents();

        for (EventData ts : testSavings) {
            String log = "from date:" + ts.getFromDate()
                    + " ,to date: " + ts.getToDate()
                    + " ,location: " + ts.getLocation()
                    + " ,title " + ts.getTitle();

            Date date = new Date();
            Date date1 = new Date();
            Log.d("Result: ", log);

            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");

            try {
                date = df.parse(ts.getFromDate());
                date1 = df.parse(ts.getToDate());
            } catch (ParseException ex) {

            }
            String timeFrom = df2.format(date);
            String startTime = String.valueOf(timeFrom);

            String timeTo = df2.format(date1);
            String endTime = String.valueOf(timeTo);


            String location = ts.getLocation();
            String title = ts.getTitle();


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    myIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            if(location.equals(""))
            {
                String msg = "From : " + startTime + "\nTo : " + endTime;

                myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .build();

            }

            else
            {
                String msg = "From : " + startTime + "\nTo : " + endTime + "\nAt : " + location;
                myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .build();

            }

            Log.i("Notify", "Notification");
            notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
Calendar object Passed in setAlarm method

     c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
            c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,2);
            notification = c.getTime();
            notificationTime = df.format(notification);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),notificationTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Thank you..

Comment: If the alarm fires when you set it, then you've given it a date/time in the past.

Comment: No. I have not. whenever I click on save the alarm raised.

Comment: Please check edited question: @Mike M

Comment: Just now I have added that, before adding day of week the problem was same.

Comment: I want this alarm to b raised every monday so I have set like that. I am in india. whatever time i enter i get the notification on that time but i get notification on current time too when i set it.

Comment: year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

Comment: current day is selected

Comment: no. Can u suggest how should I set this every monday and before 10 minutes of the event?

Comment: I checked again by removing c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,2);  ,,,but still result is same

Comment: I want to set the time from time picker so i have set the values again.

Comment: Then it seems like you've got problems elsewhere in your code. You said `day` is set for the current day - `day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`. Are you sure you're actually using the day and time the user selects before setting the `Calendar`? Also, to debug, you should check `targetmCalen.getTimeInMillis()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` when you set the alarm.

Comment: I checked with values . targetmCalen.getTimeInMillis() --- this gives the selected value from time picker and System.currentTimeMillis()---dose not show any value just alarm is raised. I think System.currentTimeMillis() gives current value. But I tried to get the calendar instance and set c.getTimeInMillis() still i get the same result.

Comment: Canyou help me with this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173227/how-to-add-event-on-specific-day?noredirect=1#comment58064781_35173227                  @Mike M

Comment: "System.currentTimeMillis()---dose not show any value" - `System.currentTimeMillis()` always has a value. "I think System.currentTimeMillis() gives current value." - Yes, that's why I suggested you compare that to the time you're giving the alarm. Keep debugging. The code you've posted, minus the `DAY_OF_WEEK` setting, works as expected for me.

Comment: minus day of week for what? getting alarm on every monday? and how about getting alarm before 10 minutes of the event?

Comment: Please check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173227/how-to-add-event-on-specific-day?noredirect=1#comment58064781_35173227

Comment: "minus day of week for what?" - I meant removing that line. That's causing the day to be reset to the first Monday of the month, which was two days ago. "how about getting alarm before 10 minutes of the event?" - You should get a single, simple alarm working first, before you try creating complex schedules.