# Select query where day of week?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, select, where-clause

I have events table contains start time, end time,dayOfWeek ,location etc. I want to retrieve records based on dayOfweek. I am saving dayOfWeek as string.("Mon","Tue",etc..).

How can I retrieve record for each day?

This is my EventTableHelper.

```
public class EventTableHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String TABLE = "event";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_FROM_DATE = "datefrom";
    private static final String KEY_TO_DATE = "dateto";
    private static final String KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK = "dayofweek";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    private static final String KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME = "notification";


    public EventTableHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE+ "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_FROM_DATE + " DATE,"
                + KEY_TO_DATE + " DATE,"
                + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME + "TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
    }
    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);

       // createTable(db);
       // onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addEvent(EventData event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE,event.getTitle());
        values.put(KEY_FROM_DATE, event.getFromDate());
        values.put(KEY_TO_DATE,event.getToDate());
        values.put(KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK,event.getDayOfWeek());
        values.put(KEY_LOCATION,event.getLocation());
        values.put(KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME,event.getNotificationTime());

        db.insert(TABLE, null, values);

        db.close();
    }

   EventData getEvent(int id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        EventData eventData = new EventData();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                        KEY_TITLE, KEY_FROM_DATE, KEY_TO_DATE, KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK, KEY_LOCATION}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

       if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
          eventData = new EventData(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                   cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6));

       }
       return eventData;
    }

    public List<EventData> getAllEvents() {
        List<EventData> conList = new ArrayList<EventData>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                EventData event = new EventData();

                event.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                event.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                event.setFromDate(cursor.getString(2));
                event.setToDate(cursor.getString(3));
                event.setDayOfWeek(cursor.getString(4));
                event.setLocation(cursor.getString(5));
                event.setNotificationTime(cursor.getString(6));

                conList.add(event);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return conList;
    }



    public int updateEvent(EventData event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE,event.getTitle());
        values.put(KEY_FROM_DATE,event.getFromDate());
        values.put(KEY_TO_DATE,event.getToDate());
        values.put(KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK,event.getDayOfWeek());
        values.put(KEY_LOCATION,event.getLocation());
        values.put(KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME,event.getNotificationTime());


        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(event.getId()) });
    }
    public void deleteEvent(EventData eventData) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(eventData.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

  }
```

I tried to retrieve like this:

```
   public List<EventData> getAllEvents(String day) {
        List<EventData> conList = new ArrayList<EventData>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE (" + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " = " + day;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                EventData event = new EventData();

                event.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                event.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                event.setFromDate(cursor.getString(2));
                event.setToDate(cursor.getString(3));
                event.setDayOfWeek(cursor.getString(4));
                event.setLocation(cursor.getString(5));
                event.setNotificationTime(cursor.getString(6));

                conList.add(event);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return conList;
    }
```

But it's giving Syntax error :

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Mon": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM event WHERE (dayofweek = Mon)
```

I am retrieving events like this:

```
String day = "Mon"
    mDb = new EventTableHelper(getActivity());
    events = mDb.getAllEvents(day);
```

I am saving dayOfWeek in another activity. I want to retrieve records in fragment. I don't have idea how to pass day parameter in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like Pass value in `single quote`

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK +" = '"+day+ "'";
```

Comment: How can I pass to function?  events = mDb.getAllEvents(); here?

Comment: @Sid use like `mDb.getAllEvents("Mon");`

Comment: Still giving exception :e.SQLiteException: near "'Mon'": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM event WHERE (dayofweek = 'Mon'

Comment: @Sid Do as per my answer...You're still did with your older code. check my answer carefully.

Comment: got it.. Thank you..@M D.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question ?:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179858/why-dose-notification-raise-while-setting-time-of-notification?noredirect=1#comment58082142_35179858

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE (" + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " = " + day;
```

To

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " = '" + day + "'";
```