# Why dose update creates new id in database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to update the record, whenever I am updating a record new id is generated with the updated values. The update should happen to the same id. What can be the reason?

Create table :

```
 public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FROM_DATE + " DATE,"
            + KEY_TO_DATE + " DATE,"
            + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME + " DATE" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
}
```

update function :

```
 public int updateEvent(EventData event) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE,event.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_FROM_DATE,event.getFromDate());
    values.put(KEY_TO_DATE,event.getToDate());
    values.put(KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK,event.getDayOfWeek());
    values.put(KEY_LOCATION,event.getLocation());
    values.put(KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME,event.getNotificationTime());


    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(event.getId()) });
}
```

Calling update function  :

```
    db = new EventTableHelper(getApplicationContext());
        eventData = new EventData();


 db.updateEvent(eventData);
```

Thank you.

EDIT :

My constructor in EventData is this:

```
 public EventData(String title,String fromDate,String toDate,String dayOfWeek,String location,String notificationTime){

    this.title = title;
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
    this.toDate = toDate;
    this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    this.location = location;
    this.notificationTime = notificationTime;

}
```

and I am adding and updating value using eventData object:

```
   db.addEvent(new EventData(eventTitle, startTime, endTime, dayOfWeek, location,notificationTime));

     db.updateEvent(eventData);
```

The id  is getting increased, I am not passing any value to id.

EventData class

```
    public class EventData  {

    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String fromDate;
    public String toDate;
    public String location;
    public String dayOfWeek;
    public String notificationTime;



    public EventData(){}
    public EventData(String title,String fromDate,String toDate, String location){

        this.title = title;
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
        this.toDate = toDate;
        this.location = location;

    }
    public EventData(int id,String title,String fromDate,String toDate,String dayOfWeek,String location,String notificationTime){

        this.title = title;
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
        this.toDate = toDate;
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
        this.location = location;
        this.notificationTime = notificationTime;

    }
   /* public EventData(String title,String fromDate,String toDate,String dayOfWeek,String location,String notificationTime){

        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
        this.toDate = toDate;
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
        this.location = location;
        this.notificationTime = notificationTime;

    }*/
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    public void setToDate(String toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }


    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }


    public void setDayOfWeek(String dayofWeek) {
        this.dayOfWeek = dayofWeek;
    }


    public void setNotificationTime(String notificationTime) {
        this.notificationTime = notificationTime;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public String getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }


    public String getDayOfWeek() {
        return dayOfWeek;
    }

    public String getNotificationTime() {
        return notificationTime;
    }
}
```

I am creating events with child view so I want to update the event on which i will click. For that i have used setTag method to pass id of view.

This is my day fragment

```
    dayplanView = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.hoursRelativeLayout);

    int id = i.getIntExtra("id",0);

    mDb = new EventTableHelper(getActivity());
    events = mDb.getAllEvents("Mon");


        int tag = 0;
        for (EventData eventData : events) {


                String datefrom = eventData.getFromDate();

                if (datefrom != null) {
                    String[] times = datefrom.substring(11, 16).split(":");
                    minutesFrom = Integer.parseInt(times[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times[1]);
                }
                String dateTo = eventData.getToDate();

                String title = eventData.getTitle();
                String location = eventData.getLocation();


                if (dateTo != null) {

                    String[] times1 = dateTo.substring(11, 16).split(":");
                    minutesTo = Integer.parseInt(times1[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times1[1]);
                }

                createEvent(inflater, dayplanView, minutesFrom, minutesTo, title, location, tag);
                tag++;

            }

    return view;
}

private void createEvent(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup dayplanView, int fromMinutes, int toMinutes, String title,String location,int tag) {
    final View eventView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_view, dayplanView, false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) eventView.getLayoutParams();

    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) eventView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) eventView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);


    if (tvTitle.getParent() != null)
       ((ViewGroup) tvTitle.getParent()).removeView(tvTitle);

    if(location.equals(""))
    {
        tvTitle.setText("Event : " + title);

    }

    else
    {

        tvTitle.setText("Event : " + title + " (At : " + location +")");

    }

    int distance = (toMinutes - fromMinutes);

    layoutParams.topMargin = dpToPixels(fromMinutes + 9);
    layoutParams.height = dpToPixels(distance);

    eventView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    dayplanView.addView(eventView);
    container.addView(tvTitle);

    eventView.setTag(tag);

    eventView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
            editMode = true;
            i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);
            int tag = 0;
            tag =(int)v.getTag();
            i.putExtra("tag",tag);
            startActivityForResult(i,1);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: The code you've shown cannot generate new IDs. Are you sure you aren't using `insertWithOnConflict()` somewhere?

Comment: No I am not using that.@CL

Comment: Why aren't you doing this  `db.update(TABLE, values, KEY_ID = id, null);` ?

Comment: It shows can not resolve symbol id.

Comment: I mean you have to pass the id dynamically.. Don't just copy paste... id means your value of KEY_ID column

Comment: Value of KEY_ID is id..    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

Comment: @user5881997 I know that bro... I am saying that id is an Integer variable you use to pass to update the row you want. That means if you want to update your row where id is 5 then value of id variable will be 5. did you understand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in comments. I think you don't need to be so complex as you are being now,

Just simply do like this,

```
db.update(TABLE, values, KEY_ID = id, null);
```

where id means the Integer value OR the value of column `KEY_ID` that you want to update. Like the value of id will be 5 if you want to update the row with id of 5.

Comment: @user5881997 Are you trying to insert a new row ?? Or trying to update the existing row ?

Comment: trying to update existing row. Whenever I click on update new record is generated.

Comment: @user5881997 Then you have to be specific which row you are trying to update in database by passing it's id or any other's values of row. You have to specify that first before updating the row. Can you update your question by adding your EventData class too ?

Comment: @user5881997 I think your problem is at event.getId() which may be always returning 0. So new record is added every time. First thing is add AUTOINCREMENT in your table creating query. Second thing check value of event.getId() by printing or Logging.

Comment: @user5881997 It's simple what you are now doing is `public EventData(String title,String fromDate,String toDate,String dayOfWeek,String location,String notificationTime)`.And here you are ignoring id. So don't ignore this. id is most important for updating existing row in database. So add id too in your constructor.

Comment: I tried his. But it then gives error on ----db.addEvent(new EventData(eventTitle, startTime, endTime, dayOfWeek, location,notificationTime));
-------- Can not rersolve constructor.

Comment: @user5881997 haha. Then simply resolve It bro. After adding the additional parameter, you have to pass that too. Match up all calling methods with its parameter. Its really simple and miner thing.

Comment: I did that still the problem is same.

Comment: If you won't have problem in future by updating the row by another value instead of id then do that. What I meant to say is that try writing `db.update(TABLE, values, KEY_TITLE = event.getTitle(), null);` by comparing title. Because you are ignoring id from the start. So ignore it there too.

Comment: solved it..Thank you..Can you help me with this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179858/why-dose-notification-raise-while-setting-time-of-notification?noredirect=1#comment58082142_35179858

Comment: @user5881997 I will watch it if I got time !!